# How to get week number per month on Power Bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a a column called Date originated that hold the a date like "Tuesday, March 21, 2022".
I want to get that week number per month but the following gives me incorrect numbers.
The following DAX: `Week of Month = 1 + WEEKNUM('ECR'[Date Originated]) - WEEKNUM(STARTOFMONTH('ECR'[Date Originated]))`
gives me 1 for that date.
Some entries are correct like for Wednesday, April 6, 2022 I do get 1

Answer (score 1):

`STARTOFMONTH` is not the right choice of function here, since that function does not by default return the first date of a given month; rather, it returns the first date of the month for the supplied dates (within the current context).

Here you are supplying only one date, and so, for example:

`=STARTOFMONTH(21/03/2022)`

will simply return `21/03/2022`.

You should be using

```
=
1 + WEEKNUM( 'ECR'[Date Originated] )
    - WEEKNUM( EOMONTH( 'ECR'[Date Originated], -1 ) + 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the DAX expression, but the date column, which you didn't share with us.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is helpful for anyone else - if you're needing this in a calendar table, based off of your date column it won't strictly work (you may have a week 5 that transitions to week 1 mid-week when a new month starts).

My workaround is creating a week ending date column like so:

Week Ending = 'Calendar'[Date] - WEEKDAY('Calendar'[Date],1)+7

Then a second column using a modified version of Jos' formula referencing the Week Ending date:

Week In Month =

1 + WEEKNUM( [Week Ending] )
- WEEKNUM( EOMONTH( [Week Ending], -1 ) + 1 )

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help someone in future...
PowerBI now has a function for this:

```
Date.WeekOfMonth([your_date])
```

I developed a workaround in DAX, but then found out this function.

Comment: Well, I gave it a minus one too soon. Indeed there is a Date.WeekOfMonth() function in M. I ended up using this - thanks! The system won't let me change the -1 unless the post is edited.